# Binding image source in Xamarin when using async data

Tags: image, xamarin, asynchronous, mvvm

I am struggling to set the image source to the value I receive from the database.
Here are relevant parts of my XAML, its code-behind and its view model.

XAML:

```
<Label Text="{Binding ViewModel_Fid}" />
<Image Source="{Binding ViewModel_ImageStream}" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected override void OnAppearing() {
            base.OnAppearing();
            myViewModel = new myViewModel();

            myViewModel.PopulateFid();
            BindingContext = myViewModel;
        }
```

View Model:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private string _fid;

public async void PopulateFid() {
            _fid = await getFid();
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ViewModel_Fid)));
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ViewModel_ImageStream)));

public MemoryStream ViewModel_ImageStream { 
            get {
                byte[] buffer = myGetBytes(_fid);
                return null == buffer ? null : new MemoryStream(buffer);    
            } 
        }
```

The problem is, ViewModel_ImageStream systematically executes BEFORE PopulateFid, which means that in ViewModel_ImageStream I always get _fid = null.
I am pretty sure this is due to PopulateFid being async, but I need it to be this way, because getFid() is an external async function.

How can I enforce that PopulateFid executes before ViewModel_ImageStream is set?

Thanks!

PS. See my solution/answer below.

Comment: does VM actually implement INotifyPropertyChanged?  You also need to make OnAppearing async, and call PopulateFid using await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ultimately worked for me was adding the Image element at runtime (i.e., not specifying it in XAML).
I add it once I've retrieved the necessary data in View Model.

So in Code-behind:

```
protected override void OnAppearing() {
            base.OnAppearing();
            myViewModel = new myViewModel();

            myViewModel.PopulateFid();
            BindingContext = myViewModel;
            myViewModel.LoadImage = (obj) => {
                var img = new Image();
                img.Source = new StreamImageSource() {
                    Stream = (token) => getstream(token)
                };
                mainstack.Children.Add(img);
            };
        }

private async Task<Stream> getstream(object token) {
            return new MemoryStream(myViewModel.myGetBytes);
        }
```

in View Model:

```
private string _fid;

public async void PopulateFid() {
            _fid = await getFid();
            LoadImg?.Invoke(true);
}
```